# Need to make something like this in views

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

[image]

It contains Title of taxonomy term, thumbnail image and a trimmed Description.
I am new to using views and adding HTML to them, can anyone help me how can i achieve this? I know basic steps but don't know what HTML should i add to achieve this kind of view.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the picture a good start? 
[image: Drupal explanation Views]
Use a field picture and text. 
Add CSS to the field picture (see picture) [image: add class]

Add a custom text
Use the replacement pattern to show picture and text.

Alter the css (with picture!) with something like 
.yourclass {float: left;}

Answer (score 1):

I think you can done this using [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) or Global Text. First add all the needed fields in view, then add a global php field or global text field. You can use the replacement patterns for all initially added fields inside this global field and format it using html. Add all initial fields as 'exclude from display' in your view. Hope this will help you.

Comment: sure, i will try. :)

Comment: @RakeshVerma the picture explains it more clearly...

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the HTML and CSS for a view. You can also enable or disable the default CSS classes.

```
1.Navigate to the edit screen for a view (for example, admin/structure/views/view/MYVIEWNAME/edit).
2.In the Fields section, click a field. The Configure Field dialog box displays.
3.Click Style Settings.
4.Enable one or more of the following options:
5.Customize Field HTML
6.Customize Label HTML
7.Customize Field and Label Wrapper HTML.
8.For each of the enabled options, specify the HTML element to wrap around the item. You can also click Create a CSS Class and specify a class name.
9.Enable or disable the Add Default Classes option. When enabled, this option specifies that the field uses Views default classes.
10.Click Apply.
```

You can create custom design of views with help of these things.
Try and revert back.